# Column info for a Sharepoint list via Graph API: getting conflicting results

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-list

I want to retrieve the column (field) names for a SharePoint list via the Graph API. According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/list-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), I can do this with an `expand` query in the request:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/xxx/lists/yyy?expand=columns
```

On testing this with a small auto-generated list in my site (and after dropping the columns with `columnGroup == "_Hidden"`), I get the following:

```
 [1] "Title"                     "ComplianceAssetId"        
 [3] "wikiCanvasId"              "wikiPageId"
 [5] "wikiTitle"                 "wikiContent"
 [7] "wikiUser"                  "wikiTimestamp"
 [9] "wikiDeleted"               "wikiSession"
[11] "wikiSpare1"                "wikiSpare2"
[13] "wikiSpare3"                "wikiConversationId"       
[15] "wikiMetadata"              "wikiOrder"
[17] "ID"                        "Modified"
[19] "Created"                   "Author"
[21] "Editor"                    "_UIVersionString"
[23] "Attachments"               "Edit"
[25] "LinkTitleNoMenu"           "LinkTitle"
[27] "DocIcon"                   "ItemChildCount"
[29] "FolderChildCount"          "_ComplianceFlags"
[31] "_ComplianceTag"            "_ComplianceTagWrittenTime"
[33] "_ComplianceTagUserId"      "_IsRecord"
[35] "AppAuthor"                 "AppEditor"
```

I then get the actual items for this list, with the request

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/xxx/lists/yyy/items?expand=fields
```

And when I check the items, they have the following field names under `fields`:

```
 [1] "@odata.etag"               "Title"
 [3] "wikiTitle"                 "wikiOrder"
 [5] "id"                        "ContentType"
 [7] "Modified"                  "Created"
 [9] "AuthorLookupId"            "EditorLookupId"
[11] "_UIVersionString"          "Attachments"
[13] "Edit"                      "LinkTitleNoMenu"
[15] "LinkTitle"                 "ItemChildCount"
[17] "FolderChildCount"          "_ComplianceFlags"
[19] "_ComplianceTag"            "_ComplianceTagWrittenTime"
[21] "_ComplianceTagUserId"      "AppAuthorLookupId"
[23] "AppEditorLookupId"         "wikiCanvasId"
[25] "wikiUser"                  "wikiTimestamp"
[27] "wikiDeleted"               "wikiMetadata"
[29] "wikiPageId"
```

Most of the column names match up, but some do not. Shouldn't they be identical?

The list in question is "Canvas items for channel {some-id}@thread.skype", if it matters.

Answer (score 0):

List/columns will contain contenttype columns, items/fields may not contain.
[FieldValueSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/fieldvalueset?view=graph-rest-1.0)
[ColumnDefinition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/columndefinition?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Comment: I don't really follow. Can you expand on this answer?

Comment: Also, if you're saying that the names obtained from the `?expand=columns` call will be a superset of those from `items`, there are some in the latter that aren't in the former